# Text Overflow - Prevent from clipping letters in half

Tags: css

For my situation, I have a fixed width in which I can show a name.
If the name is too long, then I need to clip/hide the name.

The issue I am having is the last letter is being cut in half, whereas I would only like that last whole letter to show.

In the example below for "HelloWorld!", the 'W' is cut in half.
Instead I need it to ignore that partial letter and just show "Hello".
Is this even possible with just CSS?

```css
.test {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">HelloWorld!</div>
```

Comment: Currently you could use something like `text-overflow: ellipsis` which would apply `...` where the word is cut, but to cut it and ensure that you're breaking between letters, you'd likely need something like `text-overflow: ""` (which is still "experimental" and should not be used). See more: [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: Does `text-overflow: ellipsis;` not fit your case? Or do you literally want to the last visible letter and then a cutoff?

Comment: @TylerRoper I will try that, this is an embeeded type application so as long as it works with the latest version of Chromium I will be fine.

Comment: @Callat literally want the last visible letter to be shown, do not want to use ellipsis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.test {
  width: 44px;
  height: 18px;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">HelloWorld!</div>
```

Comment: It's not perfect if `height` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `ellipsis` instead of `clip`:

```css
.test {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.test2 {
  width: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.test2>span {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">HelloWorld!</div>

<div class="test2"><span>HelloWorld!</span></div>
<div class="test2"><span>Sometext</span></div>
<div class="test2"><span>Myname</span></div>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also consider `word-break` but in this case you need to have a fixed height also:

```css
.test {
  width: 44px;
  height:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break:break-all;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">HelloWorld!</div>
<div class="test">Myname</div>
<div class="test">sometext!</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for my application ellipsis won't work.
I will be showing text on an LED display and want to show as much of the word as possible without it looking goofy with half a letter or a dot.

Comment: @bsparacino added anothe way

Comment: That other way just like Roman Maksimov works perfectly.
As you said, I do have to add a fixed height, but that is perfectly fine for what I am doing.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The text-overflow property's clip value is used to clip the text which is the default value itself when nothing is specified. This value is meant to be used for clipping only.

However there might be some cases when last letter is even clipped with `ellipsis` value. In that case you just need to make the element's display to `inline-block`

```css
span {
  max-width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span>somelong lon g text text texxt</span>
```

In this example try changing span's default display which is inline and see that text-overflow will have no effect.

And after that if you don't need `...` then you can simply add one absolutely positioned `::after` pseudo and make it background white thus removing `...` effect at the end.